# Why a curl POST request is returning a different result than this Common Library POST request to the same address with the same body?

Tags: json, rest, http, curl, common-lisp

I am using Steel Bank Common Lisp (SBCL), Emacs, Slime, and a library called [Dexador](https://github.com/fukamachi/dexador).

In the REPL, I can do:

```lisp
CL-USER> (dex:post "https://httpbin.org/post"
          :content "{\"user\": \"user1\", \"pass\":\"abcd\"}")
"{
  \"args\": {}, 
  \"data\": \"{\\\"user\\\": \\\"user1\\\", \\\"pass\\\": \\\"abcd\\\"}\", 
  \"files\": {}, 
  \"form\": {}, 
  \"headers\": {
    \"Accept\": \"*/*\", 
    \"Content-Length\": \"33\", 
    \"Content-Type\": \"text/plain\", 
    \"Host\": \"httpbin.org\", 
    \"User-Agent\": \"Dexador/0.9.15 (SBCL 2.1.9.nixos); Linux; 5.10.94\", 
    \"X-Amzn-Trace-Id\": \"Root=1-62956dc4-1b95d37752a67b8420180f71\"
  }, 
  \"json\": {
    \"pass\": \"abcd\", 
    \"user\": \"user1\"
  }, 
  \"origin\": \"189.2.84.243\", 
  \"url\": \"https://httpbin.org/post\"
}
"
```

Removing the escape character, notice the JSON key of the JSON output:

```json
  "json": {
    "pass": "abcd", 
    "user": "user1"
  }
```

Now, if I try doing the same on curl following this [tutorial](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-perform-a-post-request-using-curl), this is what I get:

```bash
$ curl -d "user=user1&pass=abcd" -X POST https://httpbin.org/post

{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "pass": "abcd", 
    "user": "user1"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Content-Length": "20", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.79.1", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-62956e50-4e880d101ac23b781fe0f9d5"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "189.2.84.243", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Notice the  `"json": null,`.

I was expecting both results to be the same since they are pointing to the same address and have the same body being sent.

Why are they different? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up `netcat`:

```
nc -l -p 3500
```

Run your `curl` command against that:

```
curl -d "user=user1&pass=abcd" -X POST http://localhost:3500/post
```

Netcat prints:

```
POST /post HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3500
User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

user=user1&pass=abcd
```

So first, `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, because that's what `-d` means to `curl`.

Second, the data is sent as `user=user1&pass=abcd`, not as JSON. That's because `curl`'s default data mode is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, it doesn't just send it as JSON because you hoped it would.
In fact, it doesn't implement JSON at all.

If you want to send JSON, you have to do that explicitly:

```
jq --null-input '
    .user |= "user1" | 
    .pass |= "abcd"' \
    | curl \
        -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
        -d @- \
        -X POST \
        https://httpbin.org/post
```

Response:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{  \"user\": \"user1\",  \"pass\": \"abcd\"}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Content-Length": "36", 
    "Content-Type": "text/plain", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.68.0", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6295a78d-0d828c3c6d3891174fd22d01"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "pass": "abcd", 
    "user": "user1"
  }, 
  "origin": "71.122.242.250", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If one open the [main github repository](https://github.com/fukamachi/dexador), he would be able to read the very first example in the `Usage` part:

```
(dex:post "https://example.com/login"
          :content '(("name" . "fukamachi") ("password" . "1ispa1ien")))
```

The form content is defined as a a-list or [association list](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node153.html). Association lists are a very important thing in Common Lisp and if the function need a a-list in parameter, you should not provide a string:

```
(dex:post "https://httpbin.org/post" :content "{\"user\": \"user1\", \"pass\": \"abcd\"}")
                                              ^ this is a string not a a-list
```

The correct function call would be:

```
(dex:post "https://httpbin.org/post"
          :content '(("user" . "user1") ("pass" . "abcd")))
```

And this returns:

```
(dex:post "https://httpbin.org/post"
          :content '(("user" . "user1") ("pass" . "abcd")))
#<(SIMPLE-ARRAY CHARACTER (464)) {
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {         ;;
    "pass": "abcd", ;; The data is here
    "user": "user1" ;;
  },                ;;
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "20",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlen... {10076E5CCF}>
200
```

Comment: I know how to use `dex:post` with alists.  But, I am afraid you did not answer my question. Why it works with a string?  Notice the answer from the other SO user, @root. While using a string, I had the same result as him with the JSON.